# how to make public_key to be table index?

Tags: smart-contract, multi-index

The contract in eos only support idx64, idx128, idx256 type for the secondary index, and key only support idx64, how can I set the public_key as the index?

The public_key in is char[34], it's length is > 256

Comment: I known in ethereum, the address can be indexed, and its lengh is 40 bytes

Comment: Why would you want to index by public key instead of by Account Name?  Account Names are indexable as they are uint64's.  And the correspond to specific public keys that can be readily retrieved from the blockchain itself.

Comment: the public_key is not relative to the account, we do offline multi signature, and allow anybody to send it to the chain @JohnHaager

Answer (score 1):

I met a similar question. It's not a good idea to make public_kay as an index (make some new key instead), but if you really want to - you can calculate sha256 of the public key and use first 64 (128 \ 256) bits as an index.